# How to save Large relational data

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, math, data-structures

Hope and pray that you all must well.

I have a scenario, in which i have to write a very large set of relational/combinational data, I am looking for a implementation technique which must be super fast. Its something like an expert system in AI.

I have 4 entities, Questions, Options, Benefits and Scenarios:

- Each question can have multiple options
- Each option can relate to single question
- On any combination of options a benefit is allocated, the allocation is called scenario
- a scenario can related to any number of options
- a scenario can relate to any number of benefits
- Each benefit can be included in multiple scenarios

Now for instance we look for an example:

- We have 4 questions, q1, q2, q3, q4
- q1 have 3 options q1o1, q1o2, q1o3
- q2 have 4 options q2o1, q2o2,q2o3,q2o4
- q3 have 5 options q3o1, q3o2,q3o3,q3o4, q3o5
- q4 have 2 options q4o1, q4o2
- scenario 1: for combination of [q1o1,q201]  a benefit **b1** is allocated
- scenario 2: for combination of [q1o1,q201,q303]  a benefit **b2** is allocated
- scenario 3: for combination of [q201,q304]  a benefit **b3** is allocated
- scenario 4: for combination of [q304,q401]  a benefit **b4** is allocated
- scenario 5: for combination of [q402]  a benefit **b5** is allocated
- scenario 6: for combination of [q1o2,q2o2,q3o1,q4o1]  a benefit **b5** is allocated

So in this way

- ( (3+1) *C* 1 x (4+1) *C* 1 x (5+1) *C* 1 x (2+1) *C* 1 ) - 1
- ( 4 x 5 x 6 x 3 ) - 1
- 360 - 1
- 359

scenarios can be build. where as *C* denote to **Combination**.

And if questions goes to 25 and each question should have 5 options

- ((5+1) ^ 25  - 1)
- 6 ^ 25 -1
- 28430288029929701375

scenarios can be build

I am looking for a best way to store this relational/combinational data to the database and want to access it back. Will wait for response of you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following set of tables will do it.

```
question:
  id
  ...

option:
  id
  question_id
  ...

option_scenario:
  option_id
  scenario_id

scenario:
  id
  option_count
  ...

scenario_benefit:
  scenario_id
  benefit_id

benefit:
  id
  ...
```

The one thing that is denormalized in the design is that `scenario.option_count` should be the count of things in `option_scenario` with that `scenario_id`.

To query it you'll need to use subqueries heavily.  Suppose that `person_option` is another table with the options a specific person has.  Then to find the benefits that that person has you'll need to:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM (
    SELECT s.scenario_id
    FROM person_option po
      JOIN scenario_option so
        ON so.option_id = po.option_id
      JOIN scenario s
        ON s.id = so.scenario_id
    WHERE po.person_id = ?
    GROUP BY so.scenario_id, s.option_count
    HAVING s.option_count = COUNT(DISTINCT po.option_id)
  ) ps
  JOIN scenario_benefit sb
    ON sb.scenario_id = ps.scenario_id
  JOIN benefit b
    ON b.id = sb.benefit_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was also reached to that solution, but was having little problem in it.

`HAVING s.option_count = COUNT(DISTINCT po.option_id)`

solves that issue. 

Really really thanks.